# restsharp latest version v110.2.0 filename encoding issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, restsharp

I'm using the latest stable version of restsharp (v110.2.0) to upload zip file to external link with name "Präsentation_Export" but after successful upload got "Pr�sentation_Export" from restsharp. I had done this work successfully working in version 105.2.3 but in v110.2.0 its not working.
below is my controller method:

```
public async Task<ApiResponse> UploadRequest(int? Id, IFormFile file, string APIEndPoint, string MethodType)
{
  ApiResponse result = new ApiResponse();
    try
    {
      var queryString = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "access_token", AccessToken } };
                Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(BaseURL + APIEndPoint, string.Empty));
                var requestUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(uri.ToString(), queryString);

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var client = new RestClient(uri);
                    await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    var restRequest = new RestRequest(requestUri, Method.Post);
                    //restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                    restRequest.AddOrUpdateParameter("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
                    
                    restRequest.AddFile("attachment", memoryStream.ToArray(), file.FileName, file.ContentType, options: new FileParameterOptions { DisableFilenameEncoding = true, DisableFileNameStar = false });

                    if (Id != null)
                    {
                        restRequest.AddParameter("generalId", Id.Value);
                    }

                    //restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;

                    var response = client.Execute(restRequest);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string resultContent = response.Content;
                        result.Data = resultContent;
                        result.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                        return result;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        string resultContent = response.Content;
                        result.ExceptionObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Exception>(resultContent);
                        result.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                        return result;


                    }
                }
                result.ExceptionObject = null;
                    result.StatusCode = 500;
                    return result;
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.ExceptionObject = ex;
                result.StatusCode = 500;
                return result;
            }


        }
```

I also tried to do the same work with following with httpclient code but still finding it hard to get successful in it:

```
                var queryString = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "access_token", AccessToken } };
                Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(BaseURL + APIEndPoint, string.Empty));
                var requestUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(uri.ToString(), queryString);

                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
                fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentType);

                content.Add(fileContent, "attachment", file.FileName);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
```

Comment: _"but no luck"_ is not really a proper description of the issue you are facing. Please describe in detail what is not working? What steps you have taken to try and figure what the problem is etc.

Comment: @phuzi, I added more detail you asked for.

Comment: What you posted shows an attempt to load an ASCII string using the wrong codepage. I suspect `DisableFilenameEncoding = true,` is the culprit. `�` is the Unicode Replacement character, used when a byte can't be converted using the specified encoding (except the 7-bit ASCII range). .NET strings are Unicode but HTTP itself has no default encoding. In the `restRequest.AddFile("attachment"` there's nothing to tell the server what's the character set of the file name.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos without using DisableFilenameEncoding = true, it'll return some random hash like name.

Comment: Your code sets `DisableFileNameStar` to `false`, which is correct, and it should work. I made a test in RestSharp and when the `filename*` is disabled (default) I can reproduce the issue. But I don't know why it still doesn't work with your code. Btw, the code in GH issue doesn't set `DisableFileNameStar`.